# How to set keyboard accessibility for a BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, accessibility

I have a BottomNavigationView in my app. I need to set keyboard accessibility i.e: when the device is connected to a physical keyboard or a D-pad and side arrows are pressed the screen should navigate between the menu items in the  BottomNavigationView, as if a BottomNavigationView's menu item is selected.
[image]